# VBA code using column header and no conditional formatting

Tags: vba, excel

In the given image, I have Project names and their start and end dates. I want to write a VBA code such that the End date is highlighted green if there is a difference of less than equal to 3 months between start and end date. Also, I want to be able to do this by using the Column header name as the column placement might change in the future. Therefore, I do not want to use conditional formatting but VBA code to write a dynamic code which works based on Column header name.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: There are so many questions like this on SO. Try searching for column header VBA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like below (this assumes that by 3 months you mean 90 days):

```
Sub foo()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
'declare and set your Sheet above, change Sheet1 as required
Dim FoundStart As Range
Dim FoundEnd As Range
LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
'get the number of rows with data from Column A
            Set FoundStart = ws.Rows(1).Find(What:="Start") 'find the header with "Start"
            Set FoundEnd = ws.Rows(1).Find(What:="End") 'find the header with "End"
            If Not FoundStart Is Nothing And Not FoundEnd Is Nothing Then 'if both headers are found then
                For i = 2 To LastRow 'loop from row 2 to last
                    If ws.Cells(i, FoundStart.Column) - ws.Cells(i, FoundEnd.Column) <= 90 Then ' if the difference between start and end is less or equal to 90 days
                        ws.Cells(i, FoundEnd.Column).Interior.ColorIndex = 4 'highlight End in Green
                    End If
                Next i
            Else
                MsgBox "Headers Not found!", vbInformation
            End If
End Sub
```

**UPDATE**

If instead of 90 days you want to highlight the rows where the month difference is 3 or less then something like this will do it:

```
Sub foo2()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
'declare and set your Sheet above, change Sheet1 as required
Dim FoundStart As Range
Dim FoundEnd As Range
LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
'get the number of rows with data from Column A
            Set FoundStart = ws.Rows(1).Find(What:="Start") 'find the header with "Start"
            Set FoundEnd = ws.Rows(1).Find(What:="End") 'find the header with "End"
            If Not FoundStart Is Nothing And Not FoundEnd Is Nothing Then 'if both headers are found then
                For i = 2 To LastRow 'loop from row 2 to last
                    MonthDiff = DateDiff("m", ws.Cells(i, FoundStart.Column), ws.Cells(i, FoundEnd.Column))
                    If MonthDiff <= 3 Then
                        ws.Cells(i, FoundEnd.Column).Interior.ColorIndex = 4 'highlight End in Green
                    End If
                Next i
            Else
                MsgBox "Headers Not found!", vbInformation
            End If
End Sub
```